# Volumetric cloud not responding to emissive body

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

[image: Hi I am trying to make an effect of the cloud being lit up by the emissive object, but it doesn't seem to be responding to the light whatsoever. If there anything that i need to toggle on or sth? Thanks a lot for help!]

Hi I am trying to make an effect of the cloud being lit up by the emissive object, but it doesn't seem to be responding to the light whatsoever. If there anything that i need to toggle on or sth? Thanks a lot for help!]

Comment: Seems to me like it's interacting, where else is the glow effect coming from? If you want the cloud to respond more to light, use an absorbtion color that is not as dark.

Comment: the glow is coming from bloom. I want the cloud to be interacting with the light as i move the light around, like in a thunderstorm. Now the cloud is the same as before and after I hide the emissive rod. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Bloom? Your question is tagge cycles. This can't be done in Eevee

Comment: Its working now! For some reasons i accidentally turned the engine to eevee. Thanks a lot for your help!!